# Browser-Caching and custom Image-Routines

Tags: image, meta-tags, browser-cache

I use META-Tags to "tell" the browser how to cache my website. Now I just wonder what the browser does when I do not insert the images directly but by a method like:

```
<img src="GetThumbnail.aspx?filenum=12"/>
```

Will caching work here like an ordinary picture? Will GetThumbnail.aspx be called once the page is cached?

Comment: you didn't add example code?!?

Comment: fixed. forgot the code-button :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

measured myself. Yes: it will be cached